# Selenium cannot find the element loaded from embedded html

Tags: html, selenium

So I'm trying to hit this "Review Agreement" button:

[image]

which has the following html code:

```
<section class="col-33 text-right">
        <button class="anchor-button bordered" ng-click="onClickReviewAgreement()">Review Agreement</button>
</section>
```

BUT apparently it's loaded from another resource, so `findElement(By.*)` doesn't work on it - I've also tried `By.xpath("/html/body/ul/li[2]/notification-bar/ul/li/section[1]/section[2]/button")`-. All the related code I'm getting in `View Page Sources` is:

```
<!-- Agreement form modal -->
    <ui-modal
        ui-modal-id="ui.modals.agreementFormModal"
        ui-modal-class="takeover agreement"
        ui-modal-controller="AgreementFormController"
        ui-modal-template-url="paths.templates + '/components/forms/tpl.agreement-form.html'"
        ui-modal-has-dimmer="true">
    </ui-modal>
```

Is there any way I can select these kinds of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to bind to `ng-click="onClickReviewAgreement()"` using css. It should be unique and css is a better and more efficient alternative to xpath

Answer (score 2):

Try using css to find the element and click thereafter -

```
WebElement buttonElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('[ng-click="onClickReviewAgreement()"]'));
buttonElement.click();
```